# React set default value from Select List after load

Tags: reactjs

I have a form that has a select list of `countries` and a cascading select list of `regions`. When a new `country` is selected, the corresponding `regions` are loaded. I am trying to set the value for the `region` after the the select list loads as the first value in the list. On page render I am loading the `country` select list here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchCountries();
  }, []);
```

When a new `country` is selected, I am triggering the corresponding `regions` to be loaded here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchRegions();
    regionData.length && setInput({...input, ["region"]: regionData[0].value})
  }, [input["country"]]);
```

This is also where I am trying to set the default `region` value as the first item in the list, but the state is not being updated. Where have I gone wrong? More code below, with non-relevant code removed for brevity.

```
export default function Signup() {
  const initialInput: SignupRequest = {
    country: "US",
    region: ""
  };

  const initialErrors: ValidationError = {
    country: "",
    region: ""
  };

  const [input, setInput] = useState<SignupRequest>(initialInput);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<ValidationError>(initialErrors);
  const [countryData, setCountryData] = useState<SelectListModel["data"]>([]);
  const [countryLoaded, setCountryLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [regionData, setRegionData] = useState<SelectListModel["data"]>([]);
  const [regionLoaded, setRegionLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCountries();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRegions();
    regionData.length && setInput({...input, ["region"]: regionData[0].value})
  }, [input["country"]]);

  function handleSelectChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setInput({ ...input, [name]: value });
  }

  function handleBlur(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    validateInput(name, value);
  }

  function validateInput(name: string, value: string | string[] | boolean) {
    let result = ValidationService.ValidateInput(name, value);
    setErrors({ ...errors, [name]: result });
  }


  function handleFormSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    // process form
  }

  async function fetchCountries() {
    const response = await LocationService.getAllCountries();
    if (response?.ok) {
      const responseData = await response.json() as CountryResponse[];
      const countries = LocationService.maptoCountrySelectList(responseData);
      setCountryData(countries);
      setCountryLoaded(true);
    }
  }

  async function fetchRegions() {
    const response = await LocationService.getRegionsByCountryCode(input["country"]);
    if (response?.ok) {
      const responseData = await response.json() as RegionResponse[];
      const regions = LocationService.maptoRegionSelectList(responseData);
      setRegionData(regions);
      setRegionLoaded(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="account-content">
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <FormGroup addClass='form-group'>
          <Label label='country' title='Country' />
          {!countryLoaded 
            ? <LoadingSpinner text="Loading..." /> 
            : <SelectList data={countryData} name='country' value={input["country"]} addClass={countryLoaded && errors["country"] ? 'is-invalid' : ''} onChange={handleSelectChange} onBlur={handleBlur} />}
            <FormError message={errors["country"]} />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup addClass='form-group'>
          <Label label='region' title='State/Region/Province' />
          {!regionLoaded 
            ? <LoadingSpinner text="Loading..." /> 
            : <SelectList data={regionData} name='region' value={input["region"]} addClass={regionLoaded && errors["region"] ? 'is-invalid' : ''} onChange={handleSelectChange} onBlur={handleBlur} />}
            <FormError message={errors["region"]} />
        </FormGroup>
        <Button type='submit' value='Sign Up' addClass='btn-mdBlue' />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setInput for region inside your fetchRegions function because setState is not synchonous so when you setRegion, and right after you setInput, region is still empty, on next render region gets filled with your previous setRegion but useEffect has already been run

```
const fetchRegions = async () => {
    const regions = await // fetchsomething
    setRegions(regions);
    setInput({ ...input, region: regions[0].value });
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion, but I get this error: `Signup.tsx:188 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`

Comment: It means that your regions are empty, add check if regions are empty, have you logged the response for regions ?

Comment: oops, my error. I was using `regionData` instead of `regions`. It's working now, thanks for your help.